# How to sum values in list?

Tags: python, list

```
list = ['1297546327:0', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:1', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:1']
```

I have a list like this and I need to add values after ":" To get it like this

```
total = ['1297546327:5','5138875960:2']
```

How can you do that??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems like maybe you should be using a dict instead of a list. That way you can assign each value before the : a value after the : and then add together all the values in the dict. Or maybe you should make two lists or use a pandas dataframe, but it seems like you are using the wrong type of datastructure for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), for example:

```
alist = ['1297546327:0', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:0', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '1297546327:1', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:1', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:0', '5138875960:1']


alist = [obj.split(':') for obj in alist]

result = {}
for k, g in groupby(sorted(alist), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    result[k] = sum(int(v) for _, v in g)

print(result)
# if you want num in ascending order (for desending order pass reverse=True to the sorted function):
# result = dict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda obj: obj[1])) 

print([f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in  result.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
{'1297546327': 5, '5138875960': 2}
['1297546327:5', '5138875960:2']
```

Comment: and you can also make it so that it goes in descending order, from the largest to the smallest value by the number after the ":"

Comment: Yes, just sort the result. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using any external module:

```py
pairs = [
    '1297546327:0',
    '1297546327:1',
    '1297546327:1',
    '1297546327:0',
    '1297546327:0',
    '1297546327:0',
    '1297546327:0',
    '1297546327:1',
    '1297546327:1',
    '1297546327:1',
    '5138875960:0',
    '5138875960:1',
    '5138875960:0',
    '5138875960:0',
    '5138875960:1'
]

d = {}

for k, v in (pair.split(':') for pair in pairs):
    d[k] = d[k] + int(v) if d.get(k) else int(v)

pairs_total = [f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in d.items()]

print(pairs_total)
```

The code above will output the following:

```py
['1297546327:5', '5138875960:2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {}
for i in lis:
    a = i.split(':')
    if dic.get(a[0]):
        dic[a[0]]=int(dic[a[0]])+int(a[1])
    else:
        dic[a[0]]=int(a[1])

total = [f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in dic.items()]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32570653)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_ = ['1297546327:0', 
     '1297546327:1', 
     '1297546327:1', 
     '1297546327:0', 
     '1297546327:0', 
     '1297546327:0', 
     '1297546327:0', 
     '1297546327:1', 
     '1297546327:1', 
     '1297546327:1', 
     '5138875960:0', 
     '5138875960:1', 
     '5138875960:0', 
     '5138875960:0', 
     '5138875960:1', 
     ]

tally = defaultdict(int)

for item in list_:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    tally[key] += int(value)

total = [f'{key}:{value}' for key, value in tally.items()]

print(total)
```

Output:

```
['1297546327:5', '5138875960:2']
```

Also note that it is bad practice to name variables the same as built-in functions and types, and other keywords like `if`, `while`, etc. Instead of `list`, name it `list_`, or simply use another name.